# F#: No abstract property was found that corresponds to this override

Tags: interface, f#, higher-order-functions

Hello fellow Overflowers. I am working on a group project to create a ray tracer that draws a 2D rendering of a 3D scene. The task I am currently on involves matrix transformation of objects (shapes), that need to be moved around, mirrored, sheared etc.

In working with shapes we have chosen to implement an interface that defines the type for a hit function. This hit function is defined in each shape, such as sphere, box, plane etc. When transforming a shape I need to transform the rays that hit the shape and the way to do that seems to be with a higher order function that alters the original hit function.

In order to do this I have implemented the function transformHitFunction, which seems to work, but the new type transformedShape, that implements the Shape interface, is giving me the error

> No abstract property was found that corresponds to this override

which doesn't make any sense to me, as it works with other hit functions of the same type. Can anyone spot what's wrong?

I have tried to strip away all modules, namespaces and code that is not relevant to this issue.

```
type Transformation = Matrix of float [,]

type Vector =
    | V of float * float * float

let mkVector x y z = V(x, y, z)
let vgetX (V(x,_,_)) = x
let vgetY (V(_,y,_)) = y
let vgetZ (V(_,_,z)) = z

type Point =
    | P of float * float * float

let mkPoint x y z = P(x, y, z)
let pgetX (P(x,_,_)) = x
let pgetY (P(_,y,_)) = y
let pgetZ (P(_,_,z)) = z

type Material = Material
    type Texture =
    | T of (float -> float -> Material)

type Shape =
    abstract member hit: Point * Vector -> (Texture*float*Vector) option

let transformPoint (p:Point) t =
    match t with
    | Matrix m -> mkPoint ((pgetX(p))*m.[0,0] + (pgetY(p))*m.[0,1] + (pgetZ(p))*m.[0,2] + m.[0,3])
                          ((pgetX(p))*m.[1,0] + (pgetY(p))*m.[1,1] + (pgetZ(p))*m.[1,2] + m.[1,3])
                          ((pgetX(p))*m.[2,0] + (pgetY(p))*m.[2,1] + (pgetZ(p))*m.[2,2] + m.[2,3])

let transformVector (v:Vector) t =
    match t with
    | Matrix m -> mkVector ((vgetX(v))*m.[0,0] + (vgetY(v))*m.[0,1] + (vgetZ(v))*m.[0,2] + m.[0,3])
                           ((vgetX(v))*m.[1,0] + (vgetY(v))*m.[1,1] + (vgetZ(v))*m.[1,2] + m.[1,3])
                           ((vgetX(v))*m.[2,0] + (vgetY(v))*m.[2,1] + (vgetZ(v))*m.[2,2] + m.[2,3])

let transformHitFunction fn (t:Transformation) =
    fun (p:Point,v:Vector) -> 
        let tp = transformPoint p t
        let tv = transformVector v t
        match fn(tp,tv) with
        | None -> None
        | Some (tex:Texture, d:float, n) -> let tn = transformVector n t
                                            Some (tex, d, tn)

type transformedShape (sh:Shape, t:Transformation) =
     interface Shape with
         member this.hit = transformHitFunction sh.hit t
```

Comment: `this.hit` isn't really a function - it needs to take some arguments

Comment: Just admit that you wrote all of this with the singular purpose of being able to write `sh.hit` ;)

Comment: Dammit, I've been caught! I even tried to hide it with the extra h...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**

When having problems with implementing or overriding members, provide the argument list *exactly* as in the abstract or virtual member's definition. (Also, mind your parentheses, because additional parentheses can change the type of a member in subtle ways.)

E.g. in this case: `member this.hit (arg1, arg2) = ...`

**Slightly longer answer**

You're encountering a situation in which the difference between F#'s first-class functions and its support of object-oriented style methods is relevant.

For compatibility with the Common Language Infrastructure's (CLI's) object-oriented languages (and object-oriented programming style in F# programs), F# sometimes discriminates between not only functions and values, but even functions in the object-oriented and functional style.

F# uses very similar syntax for two things: the "classical" CLI methods that take an argument list (and also support overloading and optional parameters) versus F#'s own favorite function type `FSharpFunc`, which always takes one parameter but supports currying and may take multiple parameters via tuples. But the semantics of these two can be different.

The last line of the question tries to pass a function with tupled input to implement a method that takes two arguments the way a method in C# or VB.NET takes them: a CLI method's argument list. Directly assigning an F#-style first-class function won't work here, and nether would a single tuple argument; the compiler insists to get every argument explicitly. If you write the implementation with its complete method argument list, it will work. For example:

```
    member this.hit (arg1, arg2) = transformHitFunction sh.hit t (arg1, arg2)
```

Another solution would be to declare `hit` as:

```
    abstract member hit: (Point * Vector -> (Texture*float*Vector) option)
```

(Note the parentheses!) Now it's a property that contains a first-class function; you can implement it by returning such a function, but the type of the member subtly changed.

The latter is why even implementing the original interface as a single-argument function, e.g. like this:

```
    member this.hit a = transformHitFunction sh.hit t a // error
```

will not work. More precisely, The compiler will refuse to see `a` as a tuple. The same issue applies to

```
     member this.hit ((arg1, arg2)) = transformHitFunction sh.hit t (arg1, arg2) // error
```

What's wrong now? The outer parentheses define the argument list, but the inner parentheses use a tuple pattern to decompose a single argument! So the argument list still has only one argument, and compilation fails. The outermost parentheses and commas when writing methods are a different feature than the tuples used elsewhere, even though the compiler translates between the two in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for your swift and in-depth reply!

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, your `transformedShape.hit` is a non-indexed property. When invoked, it returns a function that you need to provide with a `Point*Vector` tuple, and you'll get the result you want. You'll be able to see that better if you add a helper binding: Hover over `f` here:

```
type transformedShape (sh:Shape, t:Transformation) =
     interface Shape with
         member this.hit = 
            let f = transformHitFunction sh.hit t
            f
```

As others have remarked already, all you need to do is spell out the arguments explicitly, and you're good:

```
type transformedShape2 (sh:Shape, t:Transformation) =
        interface Shape with
            member this.hit(p, v) = transformHitFunction sh.hit t (p, v)
```